# Cross Object RollUp Summary with a Formula

Tags: roll-up-summary, cross-object

I have a custom object called 'transactions' associated to the standard Asset object. The Transaction object has multiple formulas to calculate $ amounts per product. We then used a formula on the Transaction object to total these individual product $ amount (Total_Transaction_Invoice_Amount__c). We'd now like to add a Rollup summary on the Asset Object to summarize the total of ALL Total_Transaction_Invoice_Amounts that are on the children records of the Asset.

I'm 99% sure this is not possible, but I want to see if others have encountered a workaround to solve for this.

Thank you!

Comment: while you can't use a formula in a RUS field, you can use a WFR to update a field using the value from the formula field. Then you cab use that in the RUS field

Comment: Or just use dlrs.